# app.default.firebase is not a function error

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I am trying to create a React Native Android app that connects to a Firebase database and getting an error when I get to "let cloud = firebase.database();" to retrieve the data.

```
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Body, Text, Button, View, H3, Table, Row, Col } from 'native-base';
import React from "react";
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

import firebase from "firebase/app";

const FirebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  }
      
export default class Chat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      people: [], 
      }        
  }

  async initializeFirebase(){
    if (firebase.apps.length) {
        await firebase.app().delete();
    }
    firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);
    
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    this.initializeFirebase();
    let cloud = firebase.database();
    
  }

  render() {
    return <Container>
      <Content>
        <Body>
            <Text>Testing</Text>
            <Text>{this.state.people.length}</Text>
        </Body>
      </Content>
    </Container>;
  }
}
```

I'm getting the [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _app.default.database is not a function. (In '_app.default.database()', '_app.default.database' is undefined)] error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `firebase/database`:

```
import 'firebase/database";
```